# AngularJS Compile Static Template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I have a template that I've included in a view that is put into the $templateCache.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="ratesPopover">
    <table class="rate-table">
        <tr ng-repeat="rate in plan.rates">
            <td>Rate</td>
            <td>{{rate}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</script>
```

I then have a directive where I want to compile the template with a scope passed in but I don't want the template to be binding. I just want the $compile service to compile the template as a static string of HTML so I can add it to a Twitter Bootstrap Popover in the data-content attribute. No two-way binding is necessary.

```
var template = angular.element('<div>' + $templateCache.get('ratesPopover') + '</div>'),
    popover = $compile(template)(scope);

element.attr('data-content', popover.html());
```

What I see when I display the popover is the compiled template without the variables interpolated. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Try to inject `$interpolate` module and then do

```
var template = '<div>' + $templateCache.get('ratesPopover') + '</div>',
    popover = $interpolate(template)(scope);

element.attr('data-content', popover);
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but my answer may help other people, I recently ran into this same problem.

To interpolate the values you need to execute scope.$apply:

```
var template = angular.element('<div>' + $templateCache.get('ratesPopover') + '</div>'),
    popover = $compile(template)(scope);

scope.$apply(function () {
    // popover is now interpolated
});
```

If you are already in a $digest cycle then calling $apply will throw an error, in this case you just need to wait until the digest cycle is over:

```
var template = angular.element('<div>' + $templateCache.get('ratesPopover') + '</div>'),
    popover = $compile(template)(scope);

$timeout(function () {
    // popover is now interpolated
});
```